# How to use jquery for this scenario?

Tags: jquery

I have following scenario - I am displaying a list of product names as link.Now,when the user hovers over the link I need to display the image of the product(the image is hidden).The html is like this (build dynamically so prod1,prod2 etc)

```
 <a id="prod1" title="product"></a>
 <div class=hidden><img src=""></img></div>
```

Comment: Why do you need javascript to achieve this? CSS has a hover selector, see my css only answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `.show()` and `.hide()`.

if you can, give links a common class so that you can do it like this...

```
$('.prod').hover(
  function{
    $(this).next('.hidden').show();
  },
  function{
    $(this).next('.hidden').hide();
  }
);
```

but if you can't change the html , you can do it like this,

```
function over(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').show();
}
function out(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').hide();
}
$('#prod1,#prod2').hover(over,out); // this will show on mouseover and hide on mouseout

// but if you just want to show and not hide do this
$('#prod1,#prod2').hover(over);
```

Comment: Take another look at your second function ;)

Comment: thanks.I wanted to show the image as source of beautytips tooltip.So,can I just say $(this).next('.hidden').bt().Now,how do I give image as source to tooltip?

Comment: @jess that depends on where you have stored your image source or link... is it in the variable? or what?

Comment: yes the image is in a variable like(using django ) product.imageurl

Comment: I don't get how you would like it to happen but you can change the image source like this your example, `$(this).next('.hidden').children('img').attr('src',product.imageurl);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like this:

```
$("#prod1").hover(function() {
  $(this).next("div").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

If you gave your links a class though, you can make it more generic, like this:

```
<a id="prod1" title="product" class="prod"></a>
```

And script like this:

```
$(".prod").hover(function() {
  $(this).next("div").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

You can also give it an effect if you want, for example an expand/fade like this:

```
$(".prod").hover(function() {
  $(this).next("div").stop(true, true).toggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to do this unless you want fancy animations.

```
 <div class="aProductLink" >
    <a id="prod1" title="product"></a>
    <div class="productHoverContent"><p>Put a description here if you need.</p><img src="bla.jpg"/></div>
 </div>
```

Css is something like this:

```
.aProductLink {
  position:relative;
  overflow:visible;
}

.productHoverContent{
  display:none;  //Hide by default
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.aProductLink:hover .productHoverContent {
  display:block; //Show in hover state.
}
```

It's the same technique as suckerfish dropdown menus.

Note that most touch screen phones have no hover state so you should consider the accessibility of this.